# numer of cities and their name, javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a text field that allow user to enter the number of cities want, and I want text field show according to that number to write the name of cities.. for example if user enter number 3 then 3 of text fields automatically should appear to write the name of these cities,, how can I do it? and what is the appropriate technicians should be used? using JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read How do I ask  a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code:

```
  <script type="application/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var element = document.getElementsByName("city");
        for (index = element.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
        }
        var l = document.getElementById('number').value;
        var parent = document.getElementById("myForm");
        for (i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("id", i);
            input.setAttribute("type", "text");
            input.setAttribute("name", "city");
            parent.appendChild(input);
        }
    }
</script>
<body> 
    <form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
        <input id="number" type="number" step="1" pattern="\d+" onchange="myFunction()"/>
    </form>
</body>
```